# Why does an interface hosting main in Java 8 not have to be public?

Tags: java, interface, java-8, program-entry-point, static-methods

Why does the following code compile and run successfully in Java 8+eclipse?

```
package package1;
interface A  
{
    static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

If A is changed to a class, the run-time requires it to be a public class, but not so for an interface. This seems inconsistent.

**EDIT:** The above statment that I made when posting the question was **WRONG**. ( I must have been tired and misread the errors ). Java does NOT require the class hosting main to be public, only the method. 
However, it is a bit inconsistent that the type hosting main does not have to be public, while the main method does.

Comment: All interface members are `public` by default.

Comment: The class doesn't have to be public. The method does.

Comment: interfaces are implicitly `public` and `static`

Comment: Is your question about the type or the method?

Comment: interfaces are NOT implicitly public. Their methods are. Turns out the run time does not require the type to be public, just the main method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If A is changed to a class, the run-time requires it to be a public class.

No it doesn't. It requires the *method* to be public, and methods in interfaces already are public.

> but not so for an interface.

Not so.

> This seems inconsistent.

It isn't. You misread the error message.

Answer (score 0):

In java prior to 1.8 static methods were not allowed.

All the methods were by default public, so  you dont have to use the keyword explicitly.

```
interface myInterface {
public void show();
//same as above
 void show();
}
```

Starting from java 8, interfaces can also have `static` methods.

Therefore you can have `static` methods but dont require the `public` keyword

```
interface myInterface {
static void main(String[] args) {}
void show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

An interface and its fields and methods are always public.

If A is a class containing the main method, then A must be public. This is because the main method is always

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: The containing class need not be public, and the final sentence is a *non sequitur.*